# FK validation within Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Good afternoon,

I have my django server running with a REST api on top to serve my mobile devices. Now, at some point, the mobile device will communicate with Django.

Let's say the device is asking Django to add an object in the database, and within that object, I need to set a FK like this:

```
objectA = ObjectA.objects.create(title=title,
    category_id = c_id, order = order, equipment_id = e_id,
    info_maintenance = info_m, info_security = info_s,
    info_general = info_g, alphabetical_notation = alphabetical_notation,
    allow_comments = allow_comments,
    added_by_id = user_id,
    last_modified_by_id = user_id)
```

If the e_id and c_id is received from my mobile devices, should I check before calling this creation if they actually still exists in the DB? That is two extra queries... but if they can avoid any problems, I don't mind!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how does the request to the REST API look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think that Django creates constraint on Foreign Key by default ( might depend on database though ). This means that if your foreign keys point to something that does not exist, then saving will fail ( resulting in Exception on Python side ).

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to a single query (it should be a single query at least, *warning I haven't tested the code*):

```
if MyObject.objects.filter(id__in=[e_id, c_id]).distinct().count() == 2:
    # create the object
    ObjectA.objects.create(...)
else:
    # objects corresponding e_id and c_id do not exist, do NOT create ObjectA
```

You should *always* validate any information that's coming from a user or that can be altered by a determined user. It wouldn't be difficult for someone to sniff the traffic and start constructing their own REST requests to your server. **Always clean and validate external data that's being added to the system.**

Comment: I think that `c_id` and `e_id` point to objects in different tables. At least naming suggests that ( `category_id` and `equipment_id` respectively ). And constraints on database were designed exactly for that.

Comment: @freakish that's the least of their problems if they're actually asking whether or not they should be validating information from outside sources through REST.